# Redirect URLs using Redirect component or htacess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

In Joomla 3.4 want to redirect this page:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/component/k2/1422-como-i...%C3%A9tica-na-sua-empresa.html
```

To this:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/item/1422-como-i...%C3%A9tica-na-sua-empresa.html
```

Using Compontent - > Redirect, I added the following redirect:

```
/component/k2/1422-como-i...ética-na-sua-empresa.html
```

Redirect to:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/item/1422-como-i...%C3%A9tica-na-sua-empresa.html
```

But this did not work.

Then I added in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.portal-gestao.com
RewriteRule ^component/k2/(.*)$ https://www.portal-gestao.com/item/$1
```

But this also doesn't work.

Help anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add redirect flag

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.portal-gestao.com
RewriteRule ^component/k2/(.*)$ https://www.portal-gestao.com/item/$1 [R=301,L]
```